# Cant connect to maven repository

Tags: maven

I am trying to do mvn clean install on my new project(because I want to download all dependencies) and I am having a problem with it.

---

```
Failed to execute goal on project Event: Could not resolve dependencies for 
project com.event:Event:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at 
org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.M3: Failed to read artifact 
descriptor for org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.M3: Could not 
transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-context:pom:5.0.0.M3 from/to central
 (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 [/172.16.0.3] 
failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

---

I was looking for an answer and find that I should check if I am behind some proxy or maybe to specify a maven repository or maybe some IDE problem. But I am not behind a proxy and my settings.xml doesn't have any proxy config and I was trying to start an mvn clean install from command line so there should not be IDE problems. Also, I am trying to download from central repo so I found that for central repo there should be no problem. Thank you in advance. :)

**My pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.event</groupId>
<artifactId>Event</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Event Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>Event</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: `Connect to 172.16.0.3:8080 failed`. That's not Central at all. Double check your settings, environment variable, others. That IP isn't popping out by itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. I found that spring dependencu on https://mvnrepository.com/tags/spring. Which settings should I check? Sorry if question is dumb. :)

Comment: mvnrepository.com is **NOT** maven central. Central is located https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 but your settings configuration is wrong...I suppose you are behind a proxy or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. I deleted C:/users/username/.m2 directory and try mvn clean install again and it worked. :)